# Как обработать hash из json?

Tags: ruby, json, хеширование

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь разобраться с простыми конструкциями руби.
Получаю массив из json данных:

```
response = JSON.parse(RESPONSE)
```

Пытаюсь его обработать таким образом:

```
class GetFilm
    attr_accessor :group_theaters :parameter

    def initialize(*catalogue)
        title = self.get_data(catalogue, "film")
        @group_theaters = title
    end

def get_data(*catalogue, parameter)
        @array = catalogue.length
    end
end
```

Отправляю данные:

```
s = GetFilm.new(response.values.to_a)
puts s.group_theaters
```

Почему-то `catalogue.length` у меня всегда 1, изначально json имеет вид:

```
'{"catalog": {
            "1": {
                "title": "Left Behind",
                "theaters": ["Ukraine", "Big World"],
                },
            "2": {
                "title": "Into the storm",
                "theaters": ["Ukraine", "Big World"],
                            }
    }}'
```

**Обновление**

```
RESPONSE1 = '{"catalog": {
            "1": {
                "title": "Left Behind", 
                "theaters": ["Ukraine", "Big World"]
                }, 
            "2": {
                "title": "Into the storm",
                "theaters": ["Ukraine", "Big World"]
                 } }}'

response = JSON.parse(RESPONSE1)
s = GetFilm.new(response.values)
```

И то, что получилось: 1

`puts catalogue` в методе `get_data` показывает массив в фигурных скобках:

```
{"1"=>{"title"=>"Left Behind", "theaters"=>["Ukraine", "Big World"]}, "2"=>{"title"=>"Into the storm", "theaters"=>["Ukraine", "Big World"]}}
```

Comment: грешно на руби делать отступы более двух пробелов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звёздочку уберите из параметров, ибо catalogue.length  вам кажет количество параметров, переданных методу.

Подробнее: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm
Смотреть Variable Number of Parameters.

Если вы решили, что звёздочка -- передача параметра по ссылке, то вы ошиблись.

Comment: Я решил, что звездочка - это объявление массива. Убрал, - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Приведи получившийся код. И то, что передаётся методу.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: JSON.parse(RESPONSE1) возвращает хеш состоящий из одного элемента. Соответственно .length это и кажет.